# Is there a way to find rows of a certain value based on the previous row?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to search in a table rows that have a certain value but the previous row has to include specific values as well. Ex.

| ID | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S | Date |
| 1 | T | Date |
| 1 | J | Date |
| 1 | C | Date |
| 2 | D | Date |
| 2 | Q | Date |
| 2 | L | Date |
| 2 | J | Date |
| 2 | C | Date |
| 3 | L | Date |
| 3 | T | Date |
| 3 | T | Date |
| 3 | C | Date |

I would just want to select on IDs that have 'C' status in column 2 when the status immediately before is 'T'.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I searched very thoroughly and I could not find an answer to this question because I am not sure if I was even asking it the right way, so I am asking here. Sorry if it's already been asked before.

Comment: You can use the LAG function here, see https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-lag/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT id, column1, column2
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY something_that_orders_the_rows
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( {- status_t -} status_c)
  DEFINE
    status_t AS column1 = 'T',
    status_c AS column1 = 'C'
);
```

or, in earlier versions, you can use the `LAG` analytic function:

```
SELECT id, column1, column2
FROM   (
  SELECT id, column1, column2,
         LAG(column1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY something_that_orders_the_rows) AS prev_c1
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  column1 = 'C'
AND    prev_c1 = 'T';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, column1, column2, something_that_orders_the_rows) AS
SELECT 1, 'S', 'Date', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'T', 'Date', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'J', 'Date', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C', 'Date', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'D', 'Date', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Q', 'Date', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'L', 'Date', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'J', 'Date', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'C', 'Date', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'L', 'Date', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'T', 'Date', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'T', 'Date', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C', 'Date', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ID | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | C | Date |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zt6cH6SK)